# Website works perfectly on local machine but breaks on live server

Tags: javascript, html

Geeks and gurus of StackO, I have a problem,

My website works well on localhost but breaks on live server. Everything active breaks and i just have a scattered static HMTL page stuck on preloaded.

My goal is to get this HTML [website](https://neuronecsl.github.io/neuronecsl/pages/) fully functional. 
The website loads and works perfectly on local host, but breaks when hosted on live server.

I have troubleshot it from 98 errors down to 14 errors representing four different errors:

1. Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
3. Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is not defined
4. Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError

I have researched and tried the solutions I found here on StackO regarding JS load order (circular references) and JavaScript placements (header/footer), and I have inspected both the demo and my site; the Scripts on the demo ([the original](https://prium.github.io/reign-IV/pages/text-left-slider.html)) and my site ([the copy](https://neuronecsl.github.io/neuronecsl/pages/)) are identical in arrangement and load order.

Can anyone unravel this mystery. Please tell me what to do to resolve each type of error.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Please post code HERE and do not rely on an external resource that will likely change to no longer show the issue

Comment: We'd need also foretellers to fix the code we can't see ...

Comment: FIRST order of the day is to click F12 and  fix console and network errors

Comment: My guess is your 2012 hoverdir does not understand your jQuery version or that some code removes jQuery since it is not available after page load

Comment: Are you using non-minified version of javascript in local and minified in production

Comment: @rajeesh Both site use the same version. Non minified, external scripts

Comment: @mplungjan   thanks for the direction.  And I think you have a point something may be  pulling out jQuery causing a domino effect (causing all dependents to fail.)  How do i investigate this?

Answer (score 0):

Start by fixing the 404 errors where you haven't uploaded the needed components to the web server (or don't have permission to access them).  A lot of the errors are calls missing information that may be downstream from these simple issues.

For #4, you have not told google to expect requests from that webpage with a valid API key.
From Google:
...
RefererNotAllowedMapError   Error
The current URL loading the Maps JavaScript API has not been added to the list of allowed referrers. Please check the referrer settings of your API key in the Google Cloud Platform Console.

See the Maps JavaScript API and Get an API Key.
...

Comment: Thanks Derek S. I am applying these now.

Comment: Accept the answer and it will improve your reputation. :)